# Break Iteration of Java loop with control flow with a recursive method

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, recursion

My attempt at recursion by trying to solve the monkey/coconut/sailor problem.

Im having issues with my for loop stopping. It just iterates though and im unsure where I went wrong.

in my 3 test cases the method testCoconuts returns the values I would like, however my loop will iterate until the last number, even if the true values are sent through the loop.

im sure its my booleans, but i havent been able to figure out what im doing wrong.

```
public class Test {

    public static boolean testCoconuts(int s, int sr, int c){

        if (c % s == 1 && sr > 0) {
            Test.testCoconuts(s, sr - 1, c - (c/s) - 1);
        }
        else if (c % s != 1) {
            return false;
        }
        else if (sr == 0) {
            System.out.println("solved");
            return true;    //returns true in all 3 test cases below
        }

        return false;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //int s and sr must me entered into the test program 
        //as the same number, ex s= 2, sr = 2

        int sailors = 3;

        Test.testCoconuts(2, 2, 7);  //will print solved
        Test.testCoconuts(3, 3, 79);  //will print solved
        Test.testCoconuts(4,4,1021);  //will print solved

        for (int testNuts = 1; testNuts < 100; testNuts++) {
            if (Test.testCoconuts(sailors, sailors, testNuts)==true) {
                System.out.println("solved!");
                break;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(testNuts);
                System.out.println("next iteration");
                System.out.println(testNuts);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Run you code under debugger step-by-step and observe.

Comment: What have you done to find out where you went wrong?  I don't see any debug tracing.  If nothing else, insert print statements for useful variables at critical points.  Also, [here](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) is some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The for-loop will run until the `testCoconouts` method equals true.

Now if you take a look at the method, there are four possible outcomes:

- `if (c % s == 1 && sr > 0)`
- `else if (c % s != 1)`
- `else if (sr == 0)`
- none of the above was satisfied

However, only in the last three of them have you explicitly stated what value the method should return.

So - in the first outcome, since nothing else is said, the method will always return false as stated outside of the if-statements. I assume you want to return the result from the recursion itself, right?

Try changing the first if-statement like this and see what happens :)

```
    if (c % s == 1 && sr > 0) {
        boolean result = Test.testCoconuts(s, sr - 1, c - (c/s) - 1);
        return result;
    }
```

(Could be done in a one-liner without the variable `result`, but I splitted it up for clarity)

Answer (score 1):

Please remember that you call your function recursively and sending a return back to the previous function call, not to the main

Here is a solution:

```
public class Test {


public static boolean testCoconuts(int s, int sr, int c){

    boolean flag = false;
    if (c % s == 1 && sr > 0){
        flag = Test.testCoconuts(s, sr - 1, c - (c/s) - 1);
    }

    else if (c % s != 1){
        return flag;
    }

    else if (sr == 0){
        System.out.println("solved");
        return true;    //returns true in all 3 test cases below
    }

    return flag;
}


 public static void main(String[] args){
   //int s and sr must me entered into the test program 
   //as the same number, ex s= 2, sr = 2

     int sailors = 3;


 //Test.testCoconuts(2, 2, 7);  //will print solved
 //Test.testCoconuts(3, 3, 79);  //will print solved
 //Test.testCoconuts(4,4,1021);  //will print solved



for (int testNuts = 1; testNuts < 100; testNuts++){
    boolean flag = Test.testCoconuts(sailors, sailors, testNuts);
    System.out.println(testNuts);
    if (flag==true){
        System.out.println("solved!");
        break;
    }
    else{
        System.out.println(testNuts);
        System.out.println("next iteration");
        System.out.println(testNuts);
    }

  }
 }
}
```